# Why is my Julia shared array code running so slow?

Tags: performance, parallel-processing, julia

I'm trying to implement Smith-Waterman alignment in parallel using Julia (see: Figure 1 of http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~rl6sf/paper_dump/2011:12:33:22.pdf), but the algorithm is running much slower in Julia than the serial version. I'm using shared arrays to do this and figure I am doing something silly that is making the code run slow. Could someone take a look and see if my code is optimized as possible? The parallel version should run faster than in serial….

The basic concept of it is to compute the anti-diagonal elements of a matrix in parallel from the upper left to lower right corner and to update them. I'm trying to use 32 cores on a shared array machine to do this. I have a SharedArray matrix that I am using to do this and am computing the elements of each anti-diagonal in parallel as shown below. The while loops in the spSW function submit tasks to workers in sync for each anti-diagonal using the helper function shared_get_score(). The main goal of this function is to fill in each element in the shared arrays "matrix" and "path".

```rb
function spSW(seq1,seq2,p)
    indel = -1
    match = 2

    seq1 = "^$seq1"
    seq2 = "^$seq2"

    col = length(seq1)
    row = length(seq2)

    wl = workers()

    matrix,path = shared_initialize_path(seq1,seq2)

    for j = 2:col
        jcol = j
        irow = 2
        @sync begin
            count = 0
            while jcol > 1 && irow < row + 1
                #println(j," ",irow," ",jcol)
                if seq1[jcol] == seq2[irow]
                    equal = true
                else
                    equal = false
                end
                w = wl[(count % p) + 1]
                @async remotecall_wait(w,shared_get_score!,matrix,path,equal,indel,match,irow,jcol)
                jcol -= 1
                irow += 1
                count += 1
            end
        end
    end

    for i = 3:row
        jcol = col
        irow = i
        @sync begin
            count = 0
            while irow < row+1 && jcol > 1
                #println(j," ",irow," ",jcol)
                if seq1[jcol] == seq2[irow]
                    equal = true
                else
                    equal = false
                end
                w = wl[(count % p) + 1]
                @async remotecall_wait(w,shared_get_score!,matrix,path,equal,indel,match,irow,jcol)
                jcol -= 1
                irow += 1
                count += 1
            end
        end
    end
    return matrix,path
end
```

The other helper functions are:

```rb
function shared_initialize_path(seq1,seq2)
    col = length(seq1)
    row = length(seq2)
    matrix = convert(SharedArray,fill(0,(row,col))) 
    path = convert(SharedArray,fill(0,(row,col)))
    return matrix,path
end

@everywhere function shared_get_score!(matrix,path,equal,indel,match,i,j)
    pathvalscode = ["-","|","M"]
    pathvals = [1,2,3]
    scores = []
    push!(scores,matrix[i,j-1]+indel)
    push!(scores,matrix[i-1,j]+indel)
    if equal
        push!(scores,matrix[i-1,j-1]+match)
    else
        push!(scores,matrix[i-1,j-1]+indel)
    end

    val,ind = findmax(scores)
    if val < 0
        matrix[i,j] = 0
    else
        matrix[i,j] = val
    end

    path[i,j] = pathvals[ind]
end
```

Does anyone see an obvious way to make this run faster? Right now it's about 10 times slower than the serial version.

Comment: How much work is being done on each `@async` call? If the answer is "very little," then this can't work: there is a certain amount of communication overhead for each `@async` call. You might be more interested in julia 0.5, which has threading support (off by default).

Comment: Yeah I realized that there is very little work being done. I think it might make sense to break the DP matrix into a grid and send larger chunks with each async call.

Comment: Could you point me to the threading support? I can't find documentation on it.

Comment: It's experimental, so there isn't any that I know of. See the `threads.jl` file in `test/` for some API demos. Currently this is very much in the category "use at your own risk, expect crashes, and be prepared to dig into the source code to figure out answers to questions."